# Inject function between calls

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-calls

> Edit: just to be clear: My question is: is it possible to dynamically
>   inject a function before all other function calls on a page.

I would like a single function to inject itself before all function calls.
I'm trying to implement access control lists for a JS app. So for eg.

User fred can access function `app.addPage()`, but he can't access function `app.removePage();`

So now how do I call the original function that was intended after calling the gatekeeper function?

I suppose I could modify my app so that every method call looks like this:

```
app.acl().functionCall();
```

But I wanted to inject `acl()` automatically before ever function call in some dynamic way. Possible?

Comment: Your description of the behavior of `alert('tomato');` after running `Function.prototype.call = function(){console.log('helloooo');}` is not accurate. Given that, it's hard to even tell what you're asking.

Comment: @Iwburk: Sorry not sure what you mean? I'm testing in the Chrome console window and adding Function.prototype.call = function(){console.log('hello')} results in all function calls on that page outputting 'hello' to the console. So eg: an alert('test') will not show an alert it will log 'hello' to the console. I'm trying to write a gatekeeper function that allows some functions to be run on a page and not others depending on the uses access levels.

Comment: @Eli_s that is not the `alert` doing the logging but the console which uses `.call`. `alert('tomato')` doesn't use `.call`

Comment: @Esailija: ahh makes sense. So looks like I'm back at square one. Just tested in Firebug and Function.prototype.call = function(){.... doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Eli_s yes, it can't be done and I cannot imagine why you would want to do this in the first place :P

Comment: Someone's going to have to ask eventually so it might as well be me: *Why?* If this is for debugging purposes then just stepping through the execution in Web Inspector/FireBug seems much easier.

Comment: hehe I want functions in my app to run only if a user belongs to a particular group. Eg a site contributor can run app.editPage(), however they cannot run app.deletePage(). Doing this centrally will allow me to control access from a single place.

Comment: People don't normally call functions on a website and even if they did they wouldn't do anything because the checks are (have to be) done server-side

Comment: @Esailija: sorry if i'm not being clear. My question is: is it possible to dynamically inject a function before all other function calls on a page. So instead of calling canUserCallThisFunction(); at the start of each function call to see if they can run this code I would like to keep a central list of functions that certain types of users can't call. Eg is a user is logged in as admin they can access any part of the app. If they are logged in as editor they can edit, but not add content etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to exert that kind of security control in a client-side app is futile. Even if you could, say, override `Function.prototype` an unprivileged user could still come along and re-override it with the original functionality. Or change a variable to make themselves privileged. Or just build a `POST` request and send it directly to the server, bypassing your script entirely. There is no way to absolutely enforce what you're trying to do in client-side code.

If, however, you're doing this for *convenience* rather than *security*, consider this:

```
// define your functions as usual
app.showCatVideo = function (...) { /* ... */ }    
app.deletePage   = function(...) { /* ... */ }
app.dropBombs    = function(...) { /* ... */ }

// specify which ones are privileged
var privilegedFunctionNames = [ "deletePage", "dropBombs" ];

for( var i = 0; i < privilegedFunctionNames.length; i++ ) {
  var funcName = privilegedFunctionNames[ i ],
    , origFunc = app[ funcName ];
  ;

  delete app[ funcName ];

  // replace the function with this one
  app[ funcName ] = function() {
    // check the user
    if( theUser.isPrivileged() ) {
      // call the original function with the arguments passed
      return origFunc.apply( app, arguments );
    }
    else {
      // hissy fit
      alert( "Unauthorized!" );
    }
  }
}
```

This just wraps the functions you specify (in `privilegedFunctionNames`) with a function that first checks if the user is privileged and, if s/he is, calls the function, and if not sounds the alarm.

Like I said, though, this has *no* security benefit. If someone knows how to use FireBug they're halfway to defeating this any any other client-side trick you could come up with.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Yes this approach is purely for the sake of convenience not security. Thank you for your awesome code ... exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Sorry: quick question: doesn't app[funcName] = function(){...} overwrite the function. Then how does return app[funcName].apply(...) know to call the original?

Comment: Ah, good catch. You have to "save" the original function before replacing it. I've updated my code.

Comment: Just got back from work and had a chance to try out some of this code. Problem is that origFunc = app[funcName], only stores a reference to the orignial function not a clone. So overwriting it still destroys the original. So, sorry but will have to remove accepted answer :(. Seems that maybe a clone of the function is necessary... seems a bit messy.. thought JS would have a more elegant way of taking care of this.

Comment: This is a one-line fix. You just have to `delete` the original function before replacing it to get rid of the reference.